# Using promises in Geofire

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, geofire

The Geofire documentation says that Geofire returns promises when reading and writing data but I cannot seem to find any examples of this. I was wondering how I could use this in javascript to attach a function onto the end of the listener that fired when the geofire promise is fulfilled. My code is:

```
var onKeyEnteredRegistration = this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
    }).then(function(result){
          console.log("promise resolved with:" + result);
        }, function(error){
          console.error(error)
        });
```

But this is outputting an error saying 'undefined is not a function' referencing the chained function. Does anyone know how to use promises in Geofire?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So only the `get`, `set` and `remove` functions on the `GeoFire` class return promises. Like so:

```
geoFire.get("some_key").then(function(location) {
  if (location === null) {
    console.log("Provided key is not in GeoFire");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Provided key has a location of " + location);
  }
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

However the `on` function instead returns a `GeoQuery` whose `on` function returns a `GeoCallbackRegistration` which is used to kill the query with the `cancel` function (which does not return anything.)

```
var onKeyEnteredRegistration = this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
     console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
});

onKeyEnteredRegistration.cancel(); // the "key_entered" event will stop firing
```